# Renaming a column: Incorrect syntax near 'SP_RENAME'.?

Tags: sql-server, sp-rename

```
ALTER TABLE [TEMP]
SP_RENAME '[TEMP].[Day]', 'GT', 'COLUMN'
```

I am trying to rename `Day` to `GT` and am getting the error

> Incorrect syntax near 'SP_RENAME'

SQL Server Management Studio says the error is on `SP_RENAME`

NOTE: I'm open to other options besides sp_rename

Comment: You can't change a column name using ALTER TABLE.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`SP_RENAME` is not part of the `ALTER TABLE` statement. It is a system stored procedure and therefore it should be invoked using the `EXEC`/`EXECUTE` statement, like this:

```
exec SP_RENAME '[TEMP].[Day]', 'GT', 'COLUMN'
```

(without the `alter table temp` bit)

Comment: I'd also add the EXEC there, in case the OP copies it into a batch and it's not the first statement.

Comment: @ericf right where juergen put it, and please don't ever say "it's not working" - what does "it's not working" mean? Do you get an error message? If so, copy and paste it so we have some clue what you mean.

Comment: [this example in sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/00034/2) not found

Comment: So just calling `sp_rename` without exec seems to work as long as it is the only statement. However when I move this statement into a conditional (to make sure the field was not already renamed) I had to add the `exec` as indicated here.

Answer (score 4):

You need to start each SP_RENAME with an EXEC

Answer (score 0):

Worked for the answer which was quoted by @juergen d.

```
PRINT N'Modifying Schema for SAMPLE_TABLE started'
DECLARE @COLNAME_DEAL_TERM VARCHAR(200) ;
SET @COLNAME_DEAL_TERM = 'SAMPLE_COL_NAME';

IF COL_LENGTH('SAMPLE', @COLNAME_DEAL_TERM ) IS NULL
BEGIN
    exec SP_RENAME 'SAMPLE.portfolio',@COLNAME_DEAL_TERM , 'COLUMN';
END;
GO
```